# Shuffle Multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I am developing a quiz application in PHP, out of 30 questions,I want to show 10 random questions to users. Using multidimensional array I am saving the questions with there options. Unable to access the random result from array.

```
$shop = array( array( question => "Q.1. What term describes hardware and software designed to help people with disabilities?", 
                      option1 => "Computer aided development",
                      option2 => "Assistive technology",
                      option3 => "Electronic learning products",
                      option4 => "Specialized support",
                    ),
               array( question => "Q.2. What is the process of simultaneously recording and compressing audio called?", 
                      option1 => "Ripcording",
                      option2 => "Audio filtering",
                      option3 => "Signal processing",
                      option4 => "Encapsulating",
                    ),
               array( question => "Q.4. Select the correct order:", 
                      option1 => "3D video games",
                      option2 => "Virtual reality",
                      option3 => "Hologram",
                      option4 => "4D Max",
                    ),
);

$rand_keys = array_rand($shop,2);

$shop[$rand_keys[0]];
```

Comment: Try `print_r($shop[$rand_keys[0]]);` Check [this](https://eval.in/450432)

Comment: Your code works just fine? http://codepad.viper-7.com/sZVTeB What issues are you having

Comment: `$shop[$rand_keys[0]];` is an array. you should be able to access the question by doing `$shop[$rand_keys[0]]['question']`. The code is also not doing anything with the array. I presume you wanted to echo it or store the result in a variable?

Comment: @JonTan, I just want to save the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned, your code works fine :P

If you want to save the result, all you have to do is
`$randomQuestion = $shop[$rand_keys[0]];`

To access the question field, just do `$randomQuestion['question']` or `$shop[$rand_keys[0]]['question'];`

If you want to grab 10 random questions:

$rand_keys = array_rand($shop, 10);

```
$questions = array();  // This array will hold the 10 random questions
foreach($rand_keys as $rand_key){
    array_push($questions, $shop[$rand_key]); // This will add the current random question into $questions
}
```

`$questions` is the array containing your 10 questions.

if you want to print all the questions,

```
foreach ($questions as $question){
    echo $question['question']. "<br>";
    echo $question['option1']. "<br>";
    echo $question['option2']. "<br>";
    echo $question['option3']. "<br>";
    echo $question['option4']. "<br>";
}
```

Comment: How to save each option separatly? like option1, option2,etc

Comment: `$option1 = $shop[$rand_keys[0]]['option1'];` will do the trick

Comment: What If i have to save 10 question do I need to do $shop[$rand_keys[0]]['question'] till $shop[$rand_keys[9]]['question']

Comment: @Roger: You could `foreach` over `$rand_keys`.

Comment: Edited the answer to show how you would do it for 10 questions.

Comment: How I can access each question from for each then, if we are pushing to a single array?

Comment: Yep. I added that too